# Compiling Borland C++ Builder 5

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-5

When I compile an old proect I have a the following error:

[Linker Fatal Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'MSHTML.LIB'

Any help with that?

Comment: Try removing MSHTML.LIB from your project file

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the lib in your C++Builder installation (with later versions at least it doesn't show) you can try generating it with the `implib` utility (found on your C++Builder bin directory), using the mshtml.dll found on your Windows directory.